# Does "alter table … set data type" functionally differ from "alter table … type"?

Tags: postgresql, performance, alter-table

The docs show `[SET DATA] TYPE` which implies the `SET DATA` part is optional, but the 9.1 release notes also imply that `SET DATA TYPE` may be different:

> Allow `ALTER TABLE ... SET DATA TYPE` to avoid table rewrites in appropriate cases

I'm trying to update a column on a billion-row table from int to bigint and I'm at the four-hour mark. I'm curious if I should cancel the transaction and restart it using the `SET DATA TYPE` form instead of the plain `TYPE` form that I used.

Does `SET DATA TYPE` do something different (and hopefully faster)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keywords in square brackets in the synopsis of SQL commands in the manual are optional. And in this case just noise. Add them or leave them, **no functional difference**. (The verbose form `SET DATA TYPE` conforms to standard SQL.)

`bigint` occupies 8 bytes, `integer` occupies 4 bytes. A table rewrite is inevitable. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

> As an exception, when changing the type of an existing column, if the
>   `USING` clause does not change the column contents and the old type is
>   either **binary coercible** to the new type or an **unconstrained domain**
>   over the new type, a table rewrite is not needed; but any indexes on
>   the affected columns must still be rebuilt.

Bold emphasis mine. Those are the "appropriate cases" that don't trigger a table rewrite since Postgres 9.1.

Comment: While it may be true in this case, I don't think that "no functional difference" is always true for bracketed parts. Consider "[IF EXISTS]": It's functionally different depending on including that or not (it could error out or not). Accepting your answer, but disagreeing that bracketed parts of commands are "just noise".

Comment: Another example would be "CREATE INDEX [ CONCURRENTLY ]" – that's definitely functionally different, yes? Regardless, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Right. Always optional, but not always noise. I was off target there. Only noise in the case at hand, though.