# Can I modify a column's data type against a live table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, performance, database-design, index, citext

I have a sparse matrix table where every attribute is `citext`. There are some indexes built against a few of the fields.

I want to change these columns back to `varchar`.

- Can I do this against a live production table, or do I need to bring down the
  database?
- Do the indexes need to be rebuilt afterwards?
- Will this result in any space savings?
- Will this give us any kind of performance boost (if those columns were heavily indexed)?

Comment: Can you run a test against a toy system? You also should consider changing to the  [TEXT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/470530) data type instead of VARCHAR (n). [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/181912/why-does-a-comparison-between-citext-and-text-fail) may also  be of interest!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Can I do this against a live production table, or do I need to bring down the database?

**Yes.** You *can* do it against a live table. Will even be very fast since `citext` and `varchar` are *binary coercible*, so no table rewrite is required (since Postgres 9.1).

**But** this still acquires an [`ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES) on the table, which makes *any* concurrent access on the table wait, and potentially fail. And if there are any indexes involving the column, those must still be rebuilt (automatically), which may take substantially longer.

**And** any dependent objects like views that use the column are road blockers and need to be removed before the change (and added back later).

Related:

- [Does "alter table … set data type" functionally differ from "alter table … type"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/256635/does-alter-table-set-data-type-functionally-differ-from-alter-table-type/256636#256636)

> - Do the indexes need to be rebuilt afterwards?

**No.** Indexes involving the column in any way have to be rebuilt, but that happens automatically. See above. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

> Indexes and simple table constraints involving the column will be automatically converted to use the new column type by reparsing the originally supplied expression.

> - Will this result in any space savings?

**No.** Binary coercible means same space on disk and in RAM. There may be a one-time effect for rebuilt indexes that are now in pristine condition - especially if those were bloated.

> - Any kind of performance boost?

Not likely. Depends on the complete picture. `citext` may or may not have been useful. I don't recommend `citext` after mixed experiences. I rather go with expression indexes. Or consider a [non-deterministic collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#COLLATION-NONDETERMINISTIC) in Postgres 12 or later.

Generally, `citext` operators are a bit slower everywhere than plain `text` / `varchar` operators. (They have to do more work.) Possible one-time effects from rewriting involved indexes can be achieved with `REINDEX` as well.

Related:

- [Can I change CITEXT columns to VARCHAR without encountering any surprise difficulties?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230614/can-i-change-citext-columns-to-varchar-without-encountering-any-surprise-difficu/230688#230688)
- [What is the overhead for varchar(n)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125499/what-is-the-overhead-for-varcharn/125526#125526)

Comment: Thank you Erwin. Will this give us any kind of performance boost if those columns were heavily indexed?

Comment: @AKWF: I added the performance item to your question & addressed it in the answer.